# How do I set sales receipt GST (sales tax or GST centre) attributes via external application? (Non US)

Tags: .net, rest, quickbooks-online, qbxml, sales-tax

I am working with a Non US version of QuickBooks online (QuickBooks Online Plus Australia). I'm trying to deal here with our Goverment services tax or GST which is 10%. What I want to do is create a sales receipt that calculates the total charge to the customer and ***displays*** the GST component through calculation. Right now the GST is being added to the charge, I simply want to acknowledge how much GST is included in the total charge.

I am using the traditional SDK QBXML for QB online (SalesTaxLineAdd). I have alternatively tried setting up the tax through the GST centre but doing so seems not to be harmonious with the SDK because when I create a sales receipt through the SDK in line with the GST centre, for the field "All Amounts Are" it automatically sets it as "Out of Scope of GST" and ideally I would want this to automatically be "Inclusive of GST". For the line Items the SDK doesn't set the "GST Which" field at all which then requires manually setting it to GST. What would be ideal is if the SDK did this all automatically.

As a workaround using the SDK and the SalesTaxLineAdd element, I have been subtracting 10% from each line item price so that "SalesTaxLineAdd" adds the 10% which then represents the true total. I will accept this If I have to but if a customer calls and asks how much they paid for their last order I will be telling them the price exclusive of gst.

If I work with the REST API v2 is it more flexible for this specific scenario?

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your solution is still the recommended solution from Intuit.

From their online documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/Tax_Inclusive.2FExclusive

> For sending TaxInclusive, the developers need to do the calculation for exclusive amount and then assign it to the lines and send the remaining tax amount in the TxnTaxDetail Line.

It also looks like their original intention was to categorize all tax amounts in this way, but the business logic and SDK end up with slightly different results:

From known issue QBO-37013: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v3_known_issues

> Business logic is assigning tax inclusive amounts to Line.Amount instead of the required tax exclusive amount when GlobalTaxCalculation='TaxInclusive'.